# Gradle configuration error

Tags: java, android, gradle

If there are two independent projects but one of them (say project A, which is an android application) rely on the other (say project B, a simple java application/library) and can't work without it. Project B, on the other hand, considered as a stand-alone application and builds and works fine by itself. Each of these projects has `settings.gradle` file in a root directory which points to a source directory.

The structure of these projects is the same and looks like this:

```
project_name_root
  project_name
    src
    build.gradle
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

`settings.gradle` has a line `include :project_name'`

And the problem is when I build the `Project A` using `Project B` as a module it throws the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':project-a'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':project-a:_debugApk'.
Project :project-a declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :project-b.
```

Project A has `settings.gradle` which contains:

```
include ':project-a', ':project-b'
project(':project-b').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../project-b-java')
```

**NOTE**

If Project B would have a little different structure (bellow) Project A will work just fine with Project B as a module. But I'd prefer to stick to the previous structure.

```
project_name_root
  src
  build.gradle
```

Comment: do you have project-b as a dependency in your `build.gradle` ?

Comment: Does project-b-java contains a "module" build.gradle file?

Comment: @Kevin DiTraglia Yes. As I added to the question, with more simple project structure without `settings.gradle` in Project B all work just fine.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti Sorry forgot to mention, yes it has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the project B has this structure:

```
project_B_root
|--project_B_module
|---- src
|---- build.gradle
|--build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
```

the path used in the `settings.gradle` of the projectA must link the `project_B_module` folder , not the `project_B_root` folder.

Comment: Thank you a lot, how could I miss it.

Comment: This worked for me to, but why I don't know why this worked :/. Thanks tho.